# Why is this Promise failing and getting a Cannot convert undefined or null to object error?

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, es6-promise

I've written this function that deletes templates. When logging through the control flow everything seems to be fine, but there's something wrong with the function that calls axios and therefore the Promise fails. Why is this.

First of all, this is the function that calls axios:

```
function remove (id) {
  console.log("template#remove - id: " + id)
  return axios.delete(API.template(id))
}
```

The id printing `34`as expected and not `"34"`

This function gets called here:

```
deleteTemplate (templateId) {
  let vc = this
  let confirmation = prompt('Por favor escriba el nombre de la plantilla si desea borrarla')
  console.log("vc.template.name: " + vc.template.name)

  if (confirmation === vc.template.name) {
    console.log("Template.remove(templateId): " + templateId)
    Template.remove(templateId)
    .then( () => {
      console.log('template-detail#deleteTemplate success')
      alert('Plantilla eliminada')
      vc.$router.push({name: 'templates'})
    })
    .catch( (error) => {
      console.log('template-detail#deleteTemplate error', error)
      console.dir(error)
      if (error.response.data.errors != undefined) {
        alert("Hubo un error eliminando la plantilla"+"\n"+error.response.data.error+"\n"+error.response.data.errors)
      } else {
        alert("Hubo un error eliminando la plantilla"+"\n"+error.response.data.error)
      }   
    })
  }
  else {
    alert('El nombre no coincide')
  }
},
```

and the id is also being printed as a number and not as a string.

I've researched a little bit about the `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error and I've concluded that I must be evaluating a strict equality on two things that aren't strictly equal. But I can't seem to find such equivalence.

EDIT:

This is API.template(id):

```
  template: function (id) {
    console.log('endpoints#template - this.templates + id:' + this.templates + id)
    return this.templates + id
  },
```

Comment: The exception could also be coming from the `then()` as the `catch` will also catch exceptions throw within the `then` method.  Just saying, it might not be coming from the `remove` method as you think it is.

Comment: @Dmase05 for Promises in general I agree with you, but inside that then() what happens isn't really stuff that's prone to errors. Actually, even if we just leave the console logging the catch will still be what's executed.

Comment: "*Cannot convert undefined or null to object*" sounds more like you are trying to access a property on it, not doing a strict comparison. But anyway, what line does the error come from? What does the stack trace say? Have you used a debugger?

Comment: @Bergi the stack trace says it's failing in return axios.delete(API.template(id))